# Can a beam search algorith with backtracking have different number solutions for different beam value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, beam-search

I am developing a **Beam Search Algorithm with Backtacking** and, when I tested the algorithm, I got different number of solutions for different beam length. So I just wanna make sure that is this possible in this algorithm or, for any beam length, the number of solutions should remain the same?So, I could make sure, the algorithm is correct or needed to be updated!

Comment: Clearly.  Otherwise, a Beam=1 search would return the same thing as a deterministic Best-First search (which is the same as a Beam=infinity search).

Comment: Thanks for the ans @RBarryYoung